# How can I add right click context menu for shell in wsl(windows subsystem linux)?

Tags: windows, powershell, terminal, registry, contextmenu

I follow https://askubuntu.com/a/867696/223991 and ran `xfce4-terminal` on Windows successfully .

That post provided a way to start xfce4-termimal from command line :

```
powershell -windowstyle hidden -Command "iex \"bash ~ -c 'DISPLAY=:0 xfce4-terminal'\" "
```

Here, `~` is the home path .

I want to create a reg file to make context menu can open xfce4-terminal, but I don't know anything about powershell and windows registry syntax, only have a registry file for `msys2` which like :

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\mingw32]
@="Open MinGW32 here"
"Icon"="C:\\msys64\\msys2.ico"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\mingw32\command]
@="C:\\msys64\\usr\\bin\\mintty -i /msys2.ico --dir \"%V/\" /bin/env MSYSTEM=MINGW32 CHERE_INVOKING=1 /usr/bin/bash -l"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\mingw32]
@="Open MinGW32 here"
"Icon"="C:\\msys64\\msys2.ico"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\mingw32\command]
@="C:\\msys64\\usr\\bin\\mintty -i /msys2.ico --dir \"%1/\" /bin/env MSYSTEM=MINGW32 CHERE_INVOKING=1 /usr/bin/bash -l"
```

what I learned from this reg file is :

1. `\"%1/\"` is the path passed in.
2. `"` and `\` need escape

I could only construct reg file like below

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\xfce4]
@="xfce4-terminal"
"Icon"="C:\\random.ico"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\xfce4\command]
@="C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe  -windowstyle hidden -Command \"iex \"bash \"%1/\" -c 'DISPLAY=:0 xfce4-terminal'\" \""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\xfce4]
@="xfce4-terminal"
"Icon"="C:\\random.ico"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\xfce4\command]
@="C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe  -windowstyle hidden -Command \"iex \"bash \"%1/\" -c 'DISPLAY=:0 xfce4-terminal'\" \""
```

But this didn't work at all , error said something like

> explorer.exe:
>       there is no application associated with file ....

So I have complete no idea how to get it work.